# Insert N zeros between elements of array

Tags: python, numpy, insert

Consider the following array `h_0 = (1/16)*np.array([1,4,6,4,1])`. What is the easiest way to insert `N`  zeros between each values of `h_0` (as part of a function)? So that I get for `N=2` for example

```py
>>> array([0.0625, 0.    , 0.    , 0.25  , 0.    , 0.    , 0.375 , 0.    ,
       0.    , 0.25  , 0.    , 0.    , 0.0625])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reshape `h_0` to 2D, stack it with zeros and then flatten the result:

```
import numpy as np

h_0 = (1/16)*np.array([1,4,6,4,1])

N = 2
zeros = np.zeros((h_0.shape[0], N))

print(np.hstack((h_0[:,None], zeros)).reshape(-1)[:-N])
# [0.0625 0. 0. 0.25 0. 0. 0.375 0. 0. 0.25 0. 0. 0.0625]
```

You can play with this [here](https://webruntime.netlify.app/#/Google_108617488638529745626/python/fbeabfc6.py).

Answer (score 2):

The simplest is probably slicing:

```
h_0 = (1/16)*np.array([1,4,6,4,1])
N = 2

out = np.zeros(h_0.size * (N+1) - N , h_0.dtype)
out[::N+1] = h_0
out
# array([0.0625, 0.    , 0.    , 0.25  , 0.    , 0.    , 0.375 , 0.    ,
#        0.    , 0.25  , 0.    , 0.    , 0.0625])
```

Comment: Nice solution!!